# Communication between 3 or more processes

Tags: windows, winapi, operating-system, ipc

How can 3 or more processes can communicate between each other? In my case I have 2 or more processes which can send information (messages) to another process (like a server). Which can be an elegant solution (not writing a lot of code) to my problem? I don't want to use sockets (I don't want to go through all TCP/IP stack for a local communication).

Comment: Perhaps named pipes?

Comment: Use one of the IPC mechanisms that you haven't yet ruled out.

Comment: Named pipes sounds good, but I need to know the number of processes that will communicate with me (a pipe is used only between two processes)

Comment: So you need two or more pipes in that case

Comment: Named pipes are not restricted to 2 processes. There can be 1 server and many clients.

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution without code, and the sockets is about the smallest (and the easiest) code you can write.
You can use also [Messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dataxchg/wm-copydata), [Named Pipes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ipc/named-pipes), or, more preferable, [File Mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/memory/file-mapping).